# Exciting skirmish: a family versus a shovel. Who wins?

Tags: arctic-scavengers

When playing with 2 players the amount of tribe members is irrelevant. Suppose that one player takes a family to the skirmish, and the other a shovel. With that, both players have fight 0. Is this a draw or the player showing the family wins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only tribe members ("people") may fight in a skirmish, so the only player that is actually involved in the skirmish is the player that had the tribe member card.

However, since you need to win a skirmish by 2 (when playing with only two players), and the tribe members have 0 attack,  the outcome of the above example skirmish would be considered a draw and the contested card would go to the junk pile.

Comment: This means that there is no requirements for you to have a fight score, right?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  One player had a person in the skirmish, the other player only had a tool card.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect my better understanding of the question.